# ReactDOM.render waits?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, synchronous

I begin to use React and I try to make some callback tests. So I made a small example in CodePen and I am very surprise of the behavior.
My example renders the button and the text as I want but I don't see the "End" text in the console.
Does that mean that ReactDOM.render "waits"?
I thought all of these were synchronous.

```
function call_back() {
  current = current + 1;
  console.log(my_var);
  console.log("current = " + current.toString());
}

function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p> hello World current = {props.current} total = {props.total}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

var my_var = 2;
var current = 1;

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <button onClick={call_back}>Click me</button>
      <MyComponent current={current} total="3"/>
    </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

console.log("end");
```

Comment: Running your code in JSFiddle works as expected https://jsfiddle.net/vgxfafoL/1/

Comment: Okay so it's due to Codepen. Thanks